# awk - Variable expansion in regex

Tags: regex, awk

Why doesn't something like this work:

```
echo 4 | awk --assign=abc=4 '/$abc/'
```

The actual example is much more complicated. Basically I have a regex I need repeated several times so I'm storing it in `abc`. Is there any way to expand an awk variable in `/<regex>/`? I've tried single and double quotes, every combination. I really need that line to be single quoted because I have several double quotes, it actually looks more like `awk --assign=test=something '/$test/ { a lot of stuff here inc $test several times with double quotes; }'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

awk doesn't use variables between `/` and `/` regex:

Following equivalent will work with same effect using `~` regex operator:

```
echo 4 | awk --assign=abc=4 '$0 ~ abc'
4
```

Comment: It's strange seeing the long option used.

Comment: Thanks. I did some research in [the gawk manual](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/gawk/gawk_5.html) but I didn't see anything about no variables in `//`. @sudo_O yeah I tried long after short didn't work (I thought maybe there was a difference). I switched back to `-v` with the answer provided.

Comment: They is not difference, just in the 500+ `awk` questions I have answered I've never seen it used. I had to actually check the `man` myself!

Comment: I find the gawk manual pretty hard to navigate. Nevertheless I found http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Using-Constant-Regexps.html
and http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Computed-Regexps.html

Comment: @glennjackman: Thanks for sharing that link (I couldn't trace that in my search).